# Converting string in python to date format

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having trouble converting a string to data format. I'm using the time module to convert a string to the YYYY-MM-DD format. The code below is what I've tried but I get the following error.

```
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'Y' as group 5; was group 3
```

Here is the code

```
import time 

review_date = "April 18, 2018"
review_date = time.strptime(review_date, '%m %d %Y %I:%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Your format is not correct. The date you are passing is in this format: `'%B %d, %Y'`. If you use month name, then its %B instead of %m.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the error is because you're using `%Y`, `%m`, and `%d` twice in your `time.strptime()` call.

Secondly, you're using the wrong format. The format you pass to `strptime()` has to match the format of the date / time string you pass, which in this case is: `%B %d, %Y`.

[This](http://strftime.org/) is a good reference on the different format types.

Comment: The problem is much more fundamental than this!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `datetime` for this:

```
from datetime import datetime
review_date = "April 18, 2018"
review_date = datetime.strptime(review_date, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This code returns review_date = '2018-04-18'. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
The date format for `April` is `%B`. `strptime()` converts to a datetime object, `.strftime()` converts the datetime object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
review_date = time.strptime(review_date, '%B %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

*time.strptime()* is for **parsing** strings into date/time structures. It takes two arguments, the string to be parsed and another string describing the format of the string to be parsed.

Try this:

```
time.strptime("April 18, 2018", "%B %d, %Y")
```

... and notice that "%B %d, %Y" is:

1. Full locale name of the month ("April")
2. [Space]
3. Date of the month (18)
4. [Comma]
5. [Space]
6. Four digit year (2018)

The format string specification that you provided bears no resemblance to the formatting of your date string.

These "magic" formatting codes are enumerated in the documentation for [time.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time 

review_date = "April 18, 2018"
review_date = time.strptime(review_date, '%B %d, %Y')
```

That's what you should have

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).